# Making a scan go into an array and add preceding text in ruby

Tags: ruby

Alright, here is my code:
(@wsource is an entered website source code)

```
@barray  = @wsource.scan(/(xxxx:|[\/|.|\w|\s]*\.(?:jp?g|gif|png))/i)  
puts @barray.collect! {|x| "http:" + x}
```

First, @wsource scans for image URLs. Then they are returned without the preceding http: (which should be there.) Trying to do line two returns

```
C:/Users/myself/workspace/Test/ripper.rb:51:in `+': can't convert String into Array (TypeError)
```

Although the ruby docs says .scan returns an array, it seems to be returning a string here. Any help, either with the regex or adding the http: appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `"http:" + x`, `x` is an Array of captures. Try this instead: `"http:" + x.first`